# What size breaker and wire for a barn feeder circuit?

Tags: electrical, wiring, circuit-breaker, subpanel

February winds blew down my overhead service to my barn.
I would like to replace the 1950's two wire service and update to a safe, sub feed using a complete new underground from a 150 amp house box.
  The current feed appears to be a branch from the upstairs outlet.(Not good.)   The total run will be 150 feet, 50 feet being the underground sub feed.

I have 4 spaces left in the house circuit breaker box that has a 150 amp main breaker. The house has electric water heat, electric oven and range and electric dryer.

Looking for max amperage and wire size to sub feed the barn that would power lights, small power tools, possibly an air compressor and a 110 mig welder.
My wife and I would not be using all the electric appliances at the same time. I am semi-retired now, but need to seek advise for this to see if I can do before spring gets here if it will be affordable to our budget.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Welcome. You might revise to explain what the other 100 feet of wiring do. Is it through the house and/or the barn? Will it be in conduit?

Comment: How deep do you want to trench it?  6", 18" or 24" of cover over top of wire/conduit?

Comment: The run would be inside from box alone ceiling 35', left turn,30' foot to outer wall, outside for the (aprox) 50' into the barn. I have looked at 2-2-2-4 Gray Stranded AL SER Cable if this would be sufficient at a 75 amp breaker feeding. Not sure if 1/0-1/0-1/0-2 Gray Stranded AL SER Cable would be better from a 100 amp breaker. Conduit is prefered and soil is such that depth is not an issue.

Comment: How many square feet is the barn?  Also, how beefy of an air compressor are we looking at here?

Comment: Right now a 110 volt, 3.5 HP, 115 psi. If possible a 240 volt would be great. Barn is approx 5,000 sq foot.

Comment: Depth is mentioned for the conduit, if I were to go with the 1/0-1/0-1/0-2 Gray Stranded AL SER Cable, what size conduit and how deep would that take for code?

Comment: How many square feet is the house for that matter, and how is the house heated/cooled?

Comment: House is aprox 1,300 sq ft and is heated with a boiler/radiator heat.

Comment: Further research is telling me that Gray Stranded AL SER Cable is not able to be buried. A product of 1/0,1/0,1/0 & #2 URD wire sounds like overkill but is this what I would need inside and out??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the activities you are talking about, I would say #4 aluminum.

The reason is 40A will probably suffice for immediate concerns, and you can do that with #8 copper *except for the distance*.  That necessitates a bump to #6 copper, and a side effect of this bump is you get some more headroom, as you can technically drive that circuit as high as 60A.

However, #4 aluminum has the same ampacity as copper at half the price, so why not use it?  At these large sizes, the fearmongering about aluminum does not apply, and these wires will be the newer alloy anyway.

Comment: I would like to max my option so that I won't regret later. Looking at distance and number of turns and best combination. For what was there, anything would be 100% better.

Comment: @KevinZirbel Well if you feel adventurous, bump it to #1 aluminum. At that point you can push it to 100A instead of 60A.

Comment: 100A would have you covered if you wanted to add electric mini split for heat/AC, or a charger for an electric car. Future owners would appreciate it.

Comment: Exactly what I was thinking!!!!

Comment: Does 1/0,1/0,1/0 & #2 URD sound like a good candidate and if so which size conduit please....

Comment: @KevinZirbel will you *ever* want to put any other wires in that conduit?

Comment: None I can think of...  its easy digging so not a problem to run a second if needed

Comment: @KevinZirbel For 1/0-1/0-1/0-2 URD looks like you'll need to use 2" conduit.  If you use Rigid (RMC) or IMC conduit, you'll need to trench to a depth of 8.5" except 14.5" where it goes under a vehicle  path (driveway etc.)  Any other type of conduit, you'll need to trench to 20.5".  Laying cable inside conduit is generally not the best idea, THWN-2 or XHHW-2 individual wires will be much easier to work with.  That can work in 1.5" conduit, but if you are DIYing you generally want to over-size conduit to make pulling easier.